# how to change values in a hidden chunk of html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this hidden block of code that i want to call based on the values that are received from server:

```
<div id="hiddenChart" style="display:none;">
    <li style="height:auto;">
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="chart_0_0">
            <div class="panel panel-success" style="width:550px; height:auto;" id="accordion_0_0">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="btn-group" style="float:right;">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" id="minimize_0_0"></i>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="close_0_0"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="panel-title">title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="height:400px;">
                    <nvd3-multi-bar-chart data="Sec1Graf1Data" id="dataChart_0_0" height="400" showXAxis="true" reduceXTicks="true" showYAxis="true" showLegend="true" showControls="true" tooltips="true">
                        <svg></svg>
                    </nvd3-multi-bar-chart>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

but i need to change some values: `ids`, `tags`, `data variables`.

I know how to show the code using `"$('ul').append($('div').html());"` but i have to change it before doing it.

How can i do it?

How do i define in which fields i have to insert the string i'me receiving?

Thk

UPDATE:

I was able put it to work, here is the fiddle with it [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLopez/5Qnhb/).
When i inspect the element, the ids that i want to change, instead of #1, it returns chart_0_0.

Thank you all for your posts and help

Comment: What do you mean by 'calling a hidden block of HTML code'? To clone it an add to another location? To just put it in another location?

Comment: Use jQuery selectors : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: `div` is not allowed as a direct child of `ul`. Your `HTML` is incorrect

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear, like say Why you cannot change things before append it to the DOM, and what do you mean by "calling" HTML markup like if was a block of executable code.

Comment: @OscarPaz yes, since it's hidden i want to clone it several times and append it in other location, that i can do.

Comment: @Pavlo after the div with the style hidden there's a li tag that as all the code that i need to add.

Comment: @KrishnaPalSingh the ul tag will be already in my main code, so i will just append the hidden chunk to it, with the changes i need.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar my question is how can i clone te hidden chunk, change it and then with jquery append command send it to the place i want

Comment: You have to be more specific with "I want to change it". jQuery allows you to change it easily as long as you know the selectors. What's holding you back?

Comment: @user3060735 Again, you have the following format: `<ul> <div> <li></li> </div> </ul>`. Am I correct? If yes, then your `HTML` is incorrect.

Comment: @Pavlo you're correct, but since the div is with the style hidden when i append it to the ul it won't be there, it only returns the content of it. here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DLopez/6N6Vh/2/

Comment: @AdrianSalazar my question is how can i mark where the changes must be and then how can i identify them. when i call the code does it saves it as a string array and i run it to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference to your div like this:

```
var $div = $('#hiddenChart');
```

To clone it,

```
var $clonedDiv = $div.clone();
```

Then, in the $cloneDiv object, you make the changes:

```
$clonedDiv.find(--selector of a node--).attr(atributeName, atributeValue); //change/add attribute
$clonedDiv.find(--selector of a node--).removeAttr(atributeName); //remove attribute
```

And so on. I won't explain how jQuery works, Lekhnath gave you a link.

Finally you insert the $clonedDiv with .appendTo() wherever you want. The original div remains untouched so you can clone it again and again.

Comment: that is what i was looking for, thank you Oscar and thank you Lekhnath

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Change text/html from a hidden div content :

Simple

1. maintain a copy of the hidden content
2. replace the content based on the element class/id selector with the server response
3. then paste the html into another div
4. replace the content of the hidden back to original (optional)

http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/ZJ3Nt/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var serverRes = {
            title: "New Title In Header",
            body: "New body text from server <\/br><nvd3-multi-bar-chart data=\"Sec1Graf1Data\" id=\"dataChart_0_0\" height=\"400\" showXAxis=\"true\" reduceXTicks=\"true\" showYAxis=\"true\" showLegend=\"true\" showControls=\"true\" tooltips=\"true\"><svg><\/svg><\/nvd3-multi-bar-chart>"
        };

        var tmpOldCont = $("#hiddenChart").html();

        var counter = 1;
        $(".serverres").click(function(){

            $("#hiddenChart").find(".panel-body").html(counter + " = " + serverRes.body);
            $("#hiddenChart").find(".panel-title").text(serverRes.title + " " + counter);
            counter++;

            $(".box-container").html($("#hiddenChart").html());
            $("#hiddenChart").html(tmpOldCont);
        });


    });
```

Comment: Thk for you're reply Austin but in this way how can i change tags and ids? for example i need to change this values from the original hidden chunk: 'id="chart_0_0"', 'id="accordion_0_0"', nvd3-multi-bar-chart.

Comment: what i need is to change the value of the ids, like "chart_0_0", the tag "nvd3-multi-bar-chart" and some other attribute values.
what i was thinking was if it's possible in the places i have to change the code insert something like #1 and when it's found, it will only replace it

Comment: Its a good idea like creating a template and having #__KEY__# and replace them with your own values.

Comment: Or you can event change the values as you wanted by accessing the element and use the attr() function to change the values

Comment: Or you can event change the values as you wanted by accessing the element and use the attr() function to change the values

Comment: i was able to make it run, but when i want to change the nvd3-multi-bar-chart tag to another one this code won't work with this code '$clonedDiv.find("div[id='#1']").attr("id", "chart_0_0");', because it's not an  attribute or a value but the tag itself.

Comment: i tried this and it works @user3060735    `tmpOldCont.find("#chart_0_0").attr("id","chart_0_1")` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/d88P6/1/)